# How to keep Gmail Clean and Organized?

Tags: gmail, google-account

Tl;Dr I am looking for ways to search and label or remove multiple emails, with the purpose of fast cleaning the email so that I am able to see with ease what is important or not

---

---

Here is a detailed list of what I would like to accomplish:

Goal 1:

- 0 emails unread in inbox
- Never miss an important email, like communications from work, collaborators, landlord, etc.

Method: Empty Inbox Mindset Model (0 emails unread in inbox)

Solution:

- Have an email account for only important communications checked daily (goal 0 emails unread), less emails are easier to manage.
- Have a separate email account for all the other digital social accounts

---

Goal 2:

- Keeping the email account with the clutter of sub-accounts organized

Situation:

- in Gmail 100+ unread emails, goal: 0 emails unread in inbox

Implications:

- all important read or unread*** emails were labeled, while keeping 0 emails unread in inbox

Context:

I open the inbox and there are 100+ emails

---

*** unread emails - most emails are useless information, some sources send mostly promotional stuff, I look there when I need the product or service, else marketing is designed to play with attention, and I like to keep my focus on what I want

Comment: please explain in plain english how I can improve this or what is the issue. both the question and the answer are for "my library" and this is what I do it at the moment.

Comment: I got here doing this research, I don't know if  this is really the right community to share this information but I was looking for ways to search and label or remove multiple emails, with the purpose of fast cleaning the email so that I am able to see with ease what is important or not

Comment: Originally posted by the OP in the question: - I am looking for ways to gain some reputation by sharing what I do.
- I hope this helps somebody and Feedback is welcomed.

Comment: This might be interesting: [Is there an etiquette for asking questions originally intended to be self-answered?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349140/289691)

Comment: Thank you Ruben I will look into that :)

Comment: Related [How should I clean out my Gmail inbox?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/11344/88163)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I do so far:

- multiple Google Accounts
- automated filters keep important emails organized
- manual cleanup when 100+ emails using smart search queries

---

Multiple Google Accounts:

- Chrome Browser Sync and multiple Users (intent specific)
- 1 Email for business related stuff
- 1 Email address for each context
  of interest

ex:

HQ business, dev programming, music, etc

*** I believe this helps also with helping the algorithms give the suggestions according to the context of interest, having a more focused online behavior based on intent.

---

Automated Filters:

- lable any important email by domain

---

Cleanup when 100+ emails: Smart Search Queries:

1. inbox > search: `has: userLabels`
2. select All > Archive (emails remain undread labeled and archived) (120/240 nice :D)
3. filter bulk unwanted emails, newsletters, promotions > label/unsubscribe/spam
4. label important emails
5. finally read the important emails
6. keep it clean
7. focus on the important: inbox search > `has:userlabels label:unread`

---

Useful resources:

- [source](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/275/how-can-i-filter-my-gmail-messages-that-arent-labeled) `has:nouserlabel` and other smart queries :D
- [auto-archive-email guide](https://www.boxysuite.com/blog/gmail-guide/auto-archive-email)